# How do I use Linq to parse a Model to two different areas on the same page

Tags: linq

I am trying to create a page that has two distinct areas. Once area is for office personnel and the other is for field personnel. I am not sure how to do this using the same model.

I can use:

```
<ul>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
<li> <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Staff" asp-action="Index"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

but that puts all of the items in the unordered list. I want to isolate them to only have the GroupName property value of "Office"

I then want to do the exact same thing on the same page looking for the items with the GroupName property value of "Field".

Is this something to be done in Linq? If so, how? Or is there a better way of doing it altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just repeating the block and add a `.Where()`condition to each, like:

```html
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(item => item.GroupName == "Office"))
{
  <li> <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Staff" asp-action="Index"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a></li>
}
</ul>

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(item => item.GroupName == "Field"))
{
  <li> <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Staff" asp-action="Index"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

If `Model` is a deferred execution `IQueryable<>` or `IEnumerable<>`, it will be evaluated twice in the above code. To avoid this, you can first force a single execution with `var ItemList = Model.ToList();` and use `ItemList` as the source in each of the loops above.

If you have more than two groups or prefer not to repeat code, you can use the LINQ `.GroupBy()` and a nested loop. Perhaps something like:

```html
@foreach (var group in Model
   .GroupBy(item => item.GroupName)
   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
   )
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(group.Key)
  <ul>
  @foreach (var item in group)
  {
    <li> <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Staff" asp-action="Index"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a></li>
  }
  </ul>
}
```